# Как сделать регулярное выражение python

Tags: python, re

Нужно с помощью модуля `re` сделать выражение, которое будет находить в тексте это: `[SBIUC]`, при этом расположение символов может быть рандомное `[BUICS] [ISUCB]` и т.д. Если хотя бы 3 символа из 5 присутствуют, то возвращать `True`. Например: `"[ISUCB]Hello, World!"` это `True`, `"[BI]Hello, World!"` это `False`, `"[IUS]Hello, World!"` это `True`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[SBIUC]{3,5}` - вся регулярка. Квадратные скобки значат - любой символ из этой последовательности, а конструктция в фигурных скобках - диапазон, сколько раз должна идти подряд предыдущая конструкция.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search(r'[SBIUC]{3,5}', '[BUICS]') is not None
True
>>> re.search(r'[SBIUC]{3,5}', '[ISUCB]') is not None
True
>>> re.search(r'[SBIUC]{3,5}', '[IUS]Hello, World!') is not None
True
>>> re.search(r'[SBIUC]{3,5}', '[BI]Hello, World!') is not None
False
```

Если важны скобки: то можно добавить `\[` вначале, и `\]` в конце. Обратный слеш - значит не воспринимать эти символы, как спецсимволы из синтаксиса регулярок.

Comment: можно использовать чуть более короткий вариант: `bool(re.search(r'[SBIUC]{3,5}', '[BUICS]'))`